# How to reverse string list in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem with reversing string list in a batch script. Let say I have a list L=string1,string2,string3 I would like to obtain reversed list L=string3,string2,string1. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your input looks like, this might be a first attempt:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET var=abc,def,ghi
SET rev=
:LOOP
IF NOT "!var!"=="" (
    FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,*" %%F IN ("!var!") DO (
        SET rev=%%F,!rev!
        SET var=%%G
    )
) ELSE (
    SET rev=!rev:~0,-1!
    GOTO ENDLOOP
)
GOTO LOOP
:ENDLOOP
ECHO reversed list is: !rev!
```

EDIT: As requested, here is an explanation how it works:

`var` is your starting list of strings separated by commas.
`rev` will be the reversed string. At the beginning this string is empty.

Now let's take a look at the loop:

In each iteration, we are separating our string into two parts: `%%F` and `%%G`. `%%F` will be everything before the first comma and `%%G` will be the rest of the string: `FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,*" %%F IN ("!var!")`. `delims=,` means that we are using comma as delimiter. `tokens=1,*` means that the first found substring will be stored in `%%F` while the rest will be stored in `%%G` (`%%F` is defined for the first token so Windows command interpreter will put every token afterwards in `G`, `H`, `I`, and so on - as we are using `*`, everything will land in `%%G`). Finally, we take the first token of our string (`%%F`) and append `,!rev!` to it. Then we set the remaining string list to everything behind the first comma (`%%G`).

In the first iteration, this loop does the following (pseudo code):

```
var=abc,def,ghi
rev=
split the string into %%F=abc and %%G=def,ghi
set rev to %%F,rev //means abc,
set var to var but without the first token //means def,ghi
```

In the second iteration:

```
var=def,ghi
rev=abc,
split the string into %%F=def and %%G=ghi
set rev to %%F,rev //means def,abc
set var to var but without the first token //means ghi
```

In the third iteration:

```
var=ghi
rev=def,abc
split the string into %%F=ghi %%G=
set rev to %%F,rev //means ghi,def,abc,
set var to var but without the first token //means empty string
```

Now, after jumping back to `:LOOP`, the **if** condition is no longer fulfilled as `!var!` has shrunk from formerly `abc,def,ghi` to now an empty string. So `IF NOT !var!==""` becomes false and we are jumping to the `ELSE` clause.

There is one problem left: as we are constructing our reversed string by pre-appending the first token from the original list AND a comma, we will end up with a comma at the end of the reversed string list: `ghi,def,abc,`

`SET rev=!rev:~0,-1!` fixes this. It takes a "substring" from our string, starting at index 0 and finishing at "end-1". So this line simply removes the last `,` at the end of our string. Then we are jumping to `:ENDLOOP`.

Comment: Thank you for a solution, I would like to understand more what you have done there. Could you explain to me what is going on in this loop.  I dont understand why there is !rev! after comma in this line `code`SET rev=%%F,!rev!. And dont know what ~0,-1 does in `code`SET rev=!rev:~0,-1!

Comment: Thank you once again, now I understand!!! I didn't consider preappending so I couldn't understand code. Now everything is clear. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You may also use this shorter/simpler approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "L=string1,string2,string3"
echo Input =%L%

set "revL="
set "str=%L:,=" & set "revL=,!str!!revL!" & set "str=%"

set "revL=%str%%revL%"
echo Output=%revL%
```

This method use the same procedure of the other answers, but in less lines. If you want to know what happens here, remove the `@echo off` line and run it. **`;)`**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file code assuming `L=string1,string2,string3` is assigned to an environment variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ListLine=L=string1,string2,string3"
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%ListLine%") do (
    set "LineBegin=%%I"
    set "ListItems=%%J"
)
set "ReversedItems="
for %%I in (%ListItems%) do call set "ReversedItems=%%I,%%ReversedItems%%"
set "ListLine=%LineBegin%=%ReversedItems:~0,-1%"
echo %ListLine%
endlocal
```

Windows command interpreter interprets a comma in list of strings in a simple **FOR** loop like a space character as it can be seen on running this batch file without `@echo off` from within a command prompt window. Therefore the second **FOR** loop runs first with `string1` assigned to loop variable `I`, second with `string2` and third with `string3`.

Command **CALL** is used to do a double processing of the command **SET** to avoid the requirement to use delayed environment variable expansion as explained by help for command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: This solution has one advantage in comparison to the other three solutions posted by Michael, Aacini, and Squashman: It produces the correct output also with one or more exclamation marks in the strings like `string1!,string2!,string3!`. But that is most likely not important for pazzdzioh. This solution fails on one or more percent signs in the strings on which the other 3 solutions work. Answers on a question with generic data are usually not 100% working for all possible use cases. This answer is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Aacini, definitely has the fastest code out of all of the answers. This is some longer code that uses a similar SET trick.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=1
set "x=abc,def,ghi"
set "x!i!=%x:,=" & set /A i+=1 & set "x!i!=%"
FOR /L %%G IN (%i%,-1,1) DO (
    IF "%i%"=="%%G" (
        set "reverse=!x%%G!"
    ) ELSE (
        set "reverse=!reverse!,!x%%G!"
    )
)
echo %reverse%
pause
```

Just some quick timed testing of all 4 answers. First one uses the original string 3 characters in each of the 3 comma separated fields.  The second one uses 3 characters in 9 comma separated fields.  Each time I tested running each one 100 times and calculated the average.  The differences are negligible.

Average of 100 tries using 3x3

```
Aacini    0.39254
Squashman 0.39851
Michael   0.3999
Mofi      0.40434
```

Average 100 tries using 3x9

```
Aacini    0.39925
Squashman 0.40278
Michael   0.41457
Mofi      0.43397
```